# Javascript cannot fire inside the ClientScriptManager

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need to check something to decide showing warning or not. The problem is the javascript didn't fire. Would someone help me why. I have searched the web and it looks like my script is fine.

There is my code:

```
Private Sub ShowWarning(ByVal ID As Integer)

    Dim ds As DataSet = reminders.getJuryPaymentDueEvent(ID)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
        Dim script As String = "javascript:confirm('There is a record and  it will be deleted')"
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "confirm", script, True)
    End If
End Sub


 Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

   If hasorder() then  'there is other function which works fine
        ShowWarning(ID)
        'if confirm return ture
        deleteOrder()
  end if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock & ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript methods do not work if the page has AJAX Update Panel.

Instead use ScriptManager's RegisterClientScriptBlock & RegisterStartupScript methods.

If your page doesn't have AJAX then debug the code putting a breakpoint to check whether the code is entering the If...Then block or not in the ShowWarning() method.

Comment: I put the breakpoint after the If stamen, the code is entering the scriptManager. However not popup confirm box

Comment: Try replacing the code with this: cs.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "confirm", script, True)

Comment: Or simply use this code without assigning object variables: Dim script As String = "javascript:confirm('There is a record and  it will be deleted')"
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "confirm", script, True)